# Compare time in R

Tags: r, time, timestamp

I have two columns, say A and B (time in HH:MM format)

```
  A       B
00:00   06:00
```

str(A) and str(B) gives "character."

I want to make a comparison like,e.g.,

```
Comment <- ifelse(hour_part(A) < hour_part(B), "Dead","NONE")
```

I want to do it in R.

How can this be done in R?

Answer (score 5):

Using this test data:

```
DF <- data.frame(A = "00:00", B = "06:00", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # test data
```

**1) character class**  This works with the original character representation:

```
hour_part <- function(x) as.numeric(sub(":.*", "", x)) # can optionally omit as.numeric
Comment <- ifelse(hour_part(DF$A) < hour_part(DF$B), "Dead", "NONE")
```

**2) times class** If this is not the only thing you want to do with `DF` then it might be better to first convert them to `"times"` class.

```
library(chron)

to.times <- function(x) times(paste0(x, ":00"))
DF2 <- transform(DF, A = to.times(A), B = to.times(B))
Comment <- ifelse(hours(DF2$A) < hours(DF2$B), "Dead", "NONE")
```

**Note:** Next time please provide the test data in reproducible form.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
ifelse(strptime(A, "%H:%M") < strptime(B, "%H:%M"), "Dead", "NONE")
```

(Note that this solution converts the hours and minutes into today's datetime)

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Christian's answer, only using `difftime`,

```
ifelse(difftime(A, B) < 0, "Dead", "None")
# [1] "Dead"
```

Data:

```
A <- strptime("00:00", "%H:%M")
B <- strptime("06:00", "%H:%M")
```