# Selecting a unique time based data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like below

```
"SERIAL_No.","DATE_","TIME_",
"13606855","2011/08/02","14:15"
```

So, a guy having a particular serial number does certain activities at different times of the day, and there is data available for a year. I want to select a single entry which corresponds to first entry after 5 AM. In this way, I will have a single entry of each serial number for a particular date. 
I tried the following but I don't know if that's gonna work:

```
df <- df[df$TIME_ >"5:00", ]
```

But this is gonna select all the entries after 5 AM. I am not sure how to achieve this. Please help, I am new to R and I wanna learn this powerful tool.

Comment: What is the class of the variable "TIME_"? Could you provide more data points as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this link ([Compare time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029812/compare-time-in-r)) has a nice function you can use `to.time` using the `chron` package. This will be useful in comparing the difference between two times.

Here is one approach:

```
# create toy data 
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(SERIAL_No = sample(5, 10, replace = TRUE),
           Date = Sys.Date() - 1:10,
           Time = format(Sys.time() - sample(1000, 10), "%H:%M"))

# Define helper function from link above
library(chron)
to.times <- function(x) times(paste0(x, ":00"))

# Change class of Time column to times
x$Time <- to.times(x$Time)

# Isolate observations past 00:00 (can switch to 5:00 when you use your data)
x <- x[x$Time > to.times("00:00"), ]

# Find observation closest to 00:00 for each serial number
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, x$SERIAL_No), 
                      function(a) a[which.min(a$Time - to.times("00:00")), ]))
```

Comment: It Works. Thank you so much